# Taylor expansion at the origin

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am confused about the following question: $\ln(1+x)=x+xg(x)$ for $x$ in a neighborhood of $0$, where $g$ is a continuous function such that $g(0)=0$. I think this may have some relation to Taylor expansion, since $\ln(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$ when I do the expansion at $0$. But I could not figure out why one can get this result $\ln(1+x)=x+xg(x)$.

Comment: You're right, it the Taylor series.  Just pull a factor of $x$ out of every term after the first.

Comment: I don't really understand what's troubling you.  Write down the Taylor series.  $\ln(1+x)= x + a_2x^2+a_3x_3+\dots=x+x(a_2x+a_3x^2+\dots)=x+xg(x)$

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the taylor expansion of $ln(1+x)$ is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^k}{k} = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-....\\
= x+ x\left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-....\right)\\
 = x+x\underbrace{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{x^k}{k+1}\right)}_{g(x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is called the Peano form of remainder:
$$\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$$
Where $f(x)=o(x)$ means that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0$$